# convert javascript to dart

Tags: javascript, dart, chart.js, dart-js-interop

I am reading 
`To leverage one of the many existing libraries written in JavaScript, use package:js. If a TypeScript type definition file exists for a JavaScript library (see DefinitelyTyped for more info), you can use the js_facade_gen tool to generate Dart code for that library.` from https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/web-programming.

I am curious how convert [javascript library](http://www.chartjs.org/) to [dart file](https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/blob/master/lib/chartjs.dart) in the example https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart. I guess there are two steps: 1, generate `TypeScript type definition file` (ts file) from the javascript library; 2, Use [js_facade_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/js_facade_gen) to convert ts file to dart.

I hope get more details. but the document is lacking. Any hints welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to convert JavaScript to Dart automatically.
`package:js` allows you to call JavaScript from Dart in Dart browser apps.

Comment: any tutorials about how to use `package:js`?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. Only the readme and the chart.js example it mentions https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js